# Securing a LAN whose wires cross over public hallway?

Tags: local-area-network, video-streaming, security

I want to record video in rooms (**A B C**) and start/stop/monitor the recordings from (only) room **D**. There is a public hallway separating **D** from the rest, and the data is sensitive.

Preliminary setup for (**A B C**):

- use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) to stream video to port N
- forward port N over SSH to room **D**

Is SSH enough to keep the data away from prying eyes?

[edit]

The whole building is owned by my company, but the hallway is "open to the public".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first seek a legal agreement with your landlord (if this is a rental property) or your college (if this is a dorm situation) and get an easement. I am skeptical of the legality of you just stringing Ethernet cable across someone else's property. No one on this site can actually help you with legal advice, however.

Yes, SSH, when used properly, will offer you somewhere between decent and very good data confidentiality and authentication across the wire. If someone were to physically cut the Ethernet cable with a pair of scissors, and splice in a hub so that they could listen in on transmissions going across that cable, the portion of the traffic encapsulated in SSH would be undecipherable to them. In order to decipher it, they would need to break into your room and take control of your private key that you used to initiate the SSH/SSL session. If you use ancient protocols such as SSL v2 and/or weaker ciphers such as RC4, it may be possible for *sophisticated* attackers to decipher the stream without needing to steal your private key, but it's doubtful that you streaming video from one apartment/dorm room to another across a hallway is important enough to draw the attention of those kind of attackers.